# ElasticSearch Get Index Names and Store Size

Tags: json, indexing, elasticsearch, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am attempting to capture a list of all the indexes and their sizes in a way that I could capture the information using Angular's $http service and then iterate through the information using the ng-repeat preferably with something like:

`<ul ng-repeat="elsindex in elsIndexHttpResponse">
    <li>{{elsindex.name}}:{{elsindex.size}}</li>
</ul>`

The closest thing I have found is this:
http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?h=index,store.size

Except:

a. its responses are not in json so easily referencing it using the ng-repeat `<li>` elements isn't going to work; and

b. i would like, if possible, to get the size output to reflect the same unit size (like bytes).

If this involves something complicated then I'd be grateful for pointers on where I should focus.

I am using elasticsearch v1.4.4

Many thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Index size in bytes is included with an [indices stats API call](http://localhost:9200/_stats/indexing,store):

`curl http://localhost:9200/_stats/indexing,store`

For nicely formatted JSON output, append [?pretty](http://localhost:9200/_stats/indexing,store?pretty) to the end of the URL:

`curl http://localhost:9200/_stats/indexing,store?pretty`

See the [Indices stats API documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html#indices-stats) for additional details and related information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually did also find these REST calls. The problem is that it doesn't respond with a dataset that can be used to get the indexname (at least not anyway I'm familiar with). It looks like there is a top level: _shards that has three children: total, _all, and indices. But the indices are just named. They are not distinguished by "name" : "value" and I think that is the reason why I cannot get to them using elsIndex.name (or something similar - seeing as how they are encapsulated by a _shards and indices objects).

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. I am marking it accepted since provides all the needed data. The reason it has taken me so long is that I've been trying to look for a different response - one that captures an array of json objects not an json object of json objects. I wanted this because I didn't understand how to parse an object of objects. I've just come to find out that the data I want is reachable through using some statements like: `$http.get("http://localhost:9200/_stats/index,store")`,  `.success(function(data) {`, `$scope.elsIndexHttpArray = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data.indices);`

Answer (score 43):

I realize this question dates already, but wanted to add my 2 cents.

http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?h=index,store.size&bytes=kb&format=json

Would actually get you exactly what you requested:

- **format=json** -> formats the output to json
- *bytes=kb* -> outputs the size in kilobytes

Information regarding the size unit was retrieved from [cat APIs doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat.html#numeric-formats)

[Possible values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#byte-units) for the bytes argument

Information regarding the format was an attempt in Sense, which has some auto-completion features quite useful to detect such options.

Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

Just a slight modification from above answer.

`curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cat/indices?h=index,store.size&bytes=gb?pretty"`

Answer (score 1):

In case you want the size of a particular index, the below API works fine on Elastic Search 7.14.
`curl http://10.29.61.105:9200/employee/_stats` where employee is the desired index name.